# React-Leaflet, supply position from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

I have following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Map, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        coordinates: []
    }
  }
}
componentDidMount() {
    // code to populate coordinates state
}
render() {
    const position = [50, 100]
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Map center={position} zoom={13}>
            <TileLayer url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png' attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      />
          <Marker position={position}>
              <Popup>
                  <span>A pretty CSS3 popup.<br/>Easily customizable.</span>
              </Popup>
          </Marker>
       </Map>
     </div>
    )
}
```

This map displays correctly unless I try to use coordinates from my state. State's output looks like this:

```
["86.765", "29.724999999999998", "0", "86.765", "29.724999999999998", "0"]
```

How would I pass this data to `position` variable and make use of it?
What I tried for now:
I defined two other states - `lat` and `lng` with corresponding values from server, and did `map` on these states to extract desired values like this:

```
let latVal = this.state.lat.map(latItem => {
    return latItem;
}
let lngVal = this.state.lng.map(lngItem => {
    return lngItem;
}
```

but when I pass it to `position` like `let position = [latVal, lngVal]` variable I get an error saying that my `latVal` is `null`, but I can `console.log` both values (`latVal` and `lngVal`) in `render()` function, in this case the output looks like this: `90.7250000000000128.105090.1649999999999929.555000000000003088.233` which I think causes an error and I'm not sure how should I transform this data to make it work.
Thanks in advance!

**UPD**
I managed to change `latVal` and `lngVal` output and my new code looks like this:

```
let arr = []
let latVal = this.state.lat.map(k => {
  arr.push(k + ' ');
})
let lngVal = this.state.lon.map(i => {
  arr.push(i + ' ');
})

const position = [50, 100];
let newArr = position.concat(arr);
```

But still no luck.

Comment: Are you asking about how to extract the values out of the output or are you asking about how to use the "position" property of the Map component?

Comment: @Teedub I think it's more about getting values from given array and use them in `position` property

Comment: position should be [lat,lng] not an array of values. Are you trying to create multiple markers from the list of values in an array ?

Comment: @AlexParij yes, exactly! I have multiple coordinate values in array and I wanna use them to show multiple markers on the map

Comment: just follow a simple example how to create multi marker list from an array of lat/lng values https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/bb2ad63023d5d6b971f60f46cac994e66c8c20a3/example/components/custom-component.js

Comment: @AlexParij thank you for referece, I've checked this example before and tried to follow it up, but the problem is that I haven't found a way how to use those coordinates numbers I get from the server as actual lat/lng, and it got me stucked like this

Comment: ok so your issue is how to take an array of values and create and array of lat-lng pairs ? from [x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3] to [[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3]] ? or from this.state.lat and this.state.lon and create an array of pairs ?

Comment: @AlexParij yes, you're right, right now I'm stucked with converting existing data to lat/lng and what I have for now is `85.34 33.55 0 90.315` i.e first number represents lat and second one is lng. I get this data by concating my this.state.lat and this.state.lon into one array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proper map over arrays that should give you want you need - an array of pairs from two states

```
this.state.lat.map((value,index)=>[value,this.state.lon[index]])
```

Comment: Alex, thank you for time you dedicated on helping me, I really appreciate it!
This `map` unction worked for me and I'm up to implementing my custom markers.